# How to manage/preserve changes to jquery(ui) libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on an web application that uses jquery and jqueryui.

IE11+ causes some problems with jqueryui autocomplete. 
When trying to scroll down the list of autocomplete results, the element keeps jumping back to the top.
I found a solution for this problem, sadly the solution requires changes to more than the blur event,

I changed the code in the "jquery-ui.js" according to

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/573e7e69c9b63752fb06a15d60ec2dded839e093

and it works as expected.

This question would be the same for jquery or any other library that requires some changes.

How can I preserver the changes to these libraries, when overwriting some events isn't enough and the libraries may be updated multiple times in the future?
I don't want to copy/paste these changes every time a new jquery version is released.

**Addendum:** As someone in the comments pointed out this change may already be part of jqueryui. 
While this would be great, I would still like to know if there is a possibility to keep changes to libraries consistent without changing the code for every update.

Comment: Just hope they merge the patch to the mainline. Otherwise you're bound to patching that part of the code at every release.

Comment: Also, I see they *did* merge the patch, so what's the problem?

Comment: @ Federico klez Culloca
I downloaded the newest version from the jqueryui site and it didn't contain the patch.
Sorry I'm just getting used to this and have no clue, when something will be merged into the mainline.